# RPC Error 32603 when deploy new Contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask, solidity-0.8.x

Im trying to deploy ERC20 contract through web3.

**Token Code (OpenZeppelin):**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply, string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

**function that im using to create a contract:**

```
    const createToken = async (name, symbol, amount, minted) => {
        
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log(accounts)

        // ERROR IS HERE
        let instance = await new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi)
            .deploy({data:Token.bytecode, arguments:[amount,name,symbol]})
            .send({from:accounts[0], gas:'1000000'});

        console.log(instance)
    }
```

**and this is an Error that i receiving when im trying to deploy new Contract:**

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":**-32603**,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: **out of gas**","code":-32000,"data":{"0x89da3df3a593cb6826f034ed803fbf5c913e7ca5cacae25899e6061bd3ed9e31":{"error":"out of gas","program_counter":1756,"return":"0x"},"stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}' {code: -32603, message: `[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{…/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}'`}
```

If i increase the gas it will show me another error:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":**-32603**,"data":{"message":"**Exceeds block gas limit**"
```

Check almost all similar post but don't find the solution(

P.S.
When i was deploying Contract via truffle, everything is fine. But when im using web3, i getting this ERROR(

Comment: Where are you deploying the contract to? Most test networks should allow 30M gas. How does the beginning of `Token.bytecode` looks like? Does it start with "0x"?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

I found I am using an HTTP_PROXY variable in my ubuntu terminal

so the solution is:

1. restart the Linux terminal without `export HTTP_PROXY=...`
2. restart ganache

everything goes fine.